# Facing "Task ':TaskName1' uses this output of task ':TaskName2' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency." error

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies, jitpack

I have been given the following gradle code to publish a library on JitPack.io:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def getGroupId = { ->
    return "com.packagename"
}

def getArtificatId = { ->
    return "ArtifactId"
}

def getVersionName = { ->
    return "0.0.1"
}


publishing {
    publications {
        LibraryName(MavenPublication) {
            groupId getGroupId()
            artifactId getArtificatId()
            version getVersionName()

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${getArtifactId()}.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                // add dependencies to pom
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    if (it.group != null &&
                            "unspecified" != it.name &&
                            it.version != null) {

                        def dependencyNode = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
        }
    }
}
```

But it is consistently failing, giving this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':LibraryName:publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal' (type 'PublishToMavenLocal').
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/jitpack/build/LibraryName/build/outputs/aar/LibraryName-release.aar'.

        Reason: Task ':LibraryName:publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal' uses this output of task ':LibraryName:bundleReleaseAar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

Possible solutions:
1. Declare task ':LibraryName:bundleReleaseAar' as an input of ':LibraryName:publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal'.
2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':LibraryName:bundleReleaseAar' from ':LibraryName:publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal' using Task#dependsOn.
3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':LibraryName:bundleReleaseAar' from ':LibraryName:publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal' using Task#mustRunAfter.

        Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
```

I have tried all the

```
tasks.named('publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal') {
    mustRunAfter tasks.named('bundleReleaseAar')
}
```

kind of solutions provided by different search results and ChatGPT and Bard but it still doesn't work.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I have been told that exactly this piece of code was working previously, like 2 months ago.